# Is there a shortcut for performing this integration (Laplace definition)

Tags: laplace-transform

My assignment for a linear systems course is to "Use the definition of the unilateral Laplace transform and an integral table to verify the following Laplace transforms, and specify their regions of convergence:"

For the first example: $\mathcal{L}[t\sin(bt)] = \dfrac{2bs}{(s^2 + b^2)^2}$

I found the integral for $t\sin(bt)$ is $-\dfrac{t\cos(bt)}{b} + \dfrac{\sin(bt)}{b^2}$ on integral-table.com, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something crucial.

If I do the integral by definition, it's $\int_{0}^{\infty}t\sin(bt)e^{-st}dt $

I would normally just think to do integration by parts to do this but the wording of the question is making me second guess myself ... how does using the integration table for this problem help me, or is it to do with the fact that the other function in the integral is $e^{-st}$?

Please do NOT simply solve the problem ... I don't want to be accused of cheating :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $t\sin(bt)e^{-st} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\sin(bt)e^{-st}$. Therefore, 
$$
\mathcal{L}\{t\sin(bt)\} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\mathcal{L}\{\sin(bt)\}
$$
Now, what is the Laplace transform of $\sin(bt)$? Once you have that, just differentiate with the respect to $s$ and multiple by $-1$.

Comment: This is sort of my issue. I already know the result ... it's more the matter of doing the whole thing by definition (i.e taking the integral), but I don't really get how an integral table helps me with that unless I find the entire integral in the table.

Comment: @DanielBall If you are integrating, what would you rather integrate $\sin(bt)e^{-st}$ or $t\sin(bt)e^{-st}$? The first choice is much easier. Then you can take the derivative.

Comment: Oh, it does make it easier to integrate, that's no doubt. I just feel like I'm missing something with the integral table ... bit. How does the integral table make the integral simpler?

Comment: Hm. Perhaps my integration table is simply inadequate, I don't see anything like those under exponentials or trig functions ... perhaps you can recommend one?

Comment: @DanielBall I refuse to use tables. I prefer to figure out the integration myself. I like to get my hands dirty; plus, relaying on a table won't make you a stronger integrator either.

Comment: Which is fine, except when the instructions explicitly state to use one :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21246/discussion-between-daniel-ball-and-dustin).